# Inserting into one table from two different tables with auto-increment value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select, insert

I'm inserting into one table from two different tables:

In my `driver` table I need to get the `driverID` to be inserted into my `car` table as a foreign key `driverID_FK`.

At the same time, I need to insert `brand`, `color`, and `wheel` from my `manufacturer` table into my `car` table.

My tables:

```
DRIVER
(driverID, name, age, ...)

CAR
(carID, driverID_FK, brand, color, wheel)

MANUFACTURER
(manufacturerID, brand, color, wheel)
```

My `driverID` is an Auto Increment value.  And in my web application, there could be other entries before or after the row that I want to insert into `car` table so it's not always necessarily the last inserted row in my `driver` table.  Same goes for my `brand, color, wheel` values in my `manufacturer` table.

Here's my Prepared SQL so far:

```
String name = //taken from another method...
int manufacturerID = //taken from another method...

String sql = "INSERT INTO car (driverID_FK, brand, color, wheel) 
+ SELECT driverID FROM driver WHERE name = ?,
+ SELECT brand, color, wheel FROM manufacturer WHERE manufacturerID = ? ;";

PreparedStatement psmt = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
psmt.setString(1, name);
psmt.setInt(2, manufacturerID);
psmt.executeUpdate();
psmt.close();
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query 1: get the driver ID:

```
SELECT driverID INTO @driverID
FROM driver
WHERE name = ?
```

Insert the manufacturer info with previous `@driverID`:

```
INSERT INTO car (driverID, brand, color, wheel)
SELECT @driverID, brand, color, wheel
FROM manufacturer
WHERE manufacturerID = ?
```

Comment: How do I execute these 2 separate queries when using Prepared Statement?  Do I declare 2 separate prepare statement variables and then execute each?

Comment: two separate prepared statements on the same connection.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using the INSERT .. SELECT syntax:

```
INSERT INTO car (driverID, brand, color, wheel)
SELECT driverID, brand, color, wheel
FROM driver, manufacturer
WHERE name = ? AND  manufacturerID = ?
```

Comment: When I test this out, it works however it's inserting the same row 4 times.  Does that have something to do with the SQL?  Because I checked everywhere in my other code and my function is only being called once so it should only insert the row once.

Comment: Its probably the query. I was guessing slightly. Does appending `LIMIT 1` help?

Comment: Yes, `LIMIT 1` makes it so that it only inserts one row.  I'm curious as to where in your query makes it so that it inserts multiple rows...

Comment: Being a comma, its effectively a join without a join criteria. I'm going do a better answer as I don't even like this much (I always hate joins without criteria).